# NoSuchMethodError while executing TestNG Test Case

Tags: automated-tests, testng-eclipse

I am trying to execute Test Cases using TestNG but i am facing NoSuchMethodError. I didn't understand the issue, as i am a beginner to this sections.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen Release 4.7.0 and TestNG 7.0.

[image]

Comment: We need your code, not just a screeshot

Comment: link:- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W5WwUw_I0K8-4_n55dxwNX25i4vqkLpx

Comment: Please find the attached link to navigate to my project folder

Comment: For all the TESTNG TESCASES,i am getting the same error.Please let mw know the solution on ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure there is only one testng on your classpath.
Go to eclipse and press CTRL+SHIFT+R. Type .classpath and select the file in your project and check.